# bison info doc - precedence in recursive parsing

Tags: parsing, bison, operator-precedence

in info doc of bison, it is mentioned that rule gets its precendence from last terminal symbol.
pasted below:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/How-Precedence.html#How-Precedence

The first effect of the precedence declarations is to assign precedence levels to the terminal symbols declared. The second effect is to assign precedence levels to certain rules: each rule gets its precedence from the last terminal symbol mentioned in the components.

For below example, how the parsing will happen if above is the case:

```
nonterm1 : nonterm2
                 | nonterm1 term1 nonterm3 nonterm4
                 | nonterm1 term2 nonterm5 nonterm6
```

One more example:

```
nonterm1 : nonterm2 nonterm3
                  | nonterm1 term1 nonterm2 nonterm3
                  | nonterm1 term2 nonterm2 nonterm3
```

Consider first example. First parser will consume `nonterm2`  then for `term1` rule, `nonterm1` will hold `nonterm2` value and `term2` higher precedence than `term1`, parser have to pass value to `nonterm1` in `term2` rule but it is invalid if we provide `term1` precedence to `term1` rule because as the statement suggests, last terminal token gives rule precedence. Assigning value of `nonterm3 nonterm4` to `nonterm1` in `term2` rule is not possible or is it?

Value is for term or nonterm but not partial set of symbols in rule or is it possible?

Does the info doc says last terminal symbol meant to be "last but one" symbol which if it is terminal?

Comment: In order to understand how precedence works in an LR parser, you need to first understand the LR parsing algorithm. I answered the question strictly as asked, but I think the underlying question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The precedence of a production is, by default, the declared precedence of the last terminal on the right-hand side of the production, regardless of how many (or few) non-terminals follow.

If that terminal does not have a declared precedence, then the production also has no declared precedence.

Precedence is declared using `%left`, `%right`, `%precedence` and `%nonassoc` declarations in the prologue.

Precedence is only used to resolve ambiguity. If the grammar fully determines the parsing action, precedence levels are not consulted.